# Thread safety of UuidCreateSequential and p/invoke calls in general

Tags: .net, pinvoke, thread-safety, guid

I am working with a system that uses GUIDs as keys in most database tables. The guids are created using *UuidCreateSequential*, in order to be nice to the database indexes.

C++ syntax, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379322(VS.85).aspx :

```
RPC_STATUS RPC_ENTRY UuidCreateSequential(
    UUID __RPC_FAR *Uuid
);
```

p/invoke.net suggests the following signature:

```
[DllImport("rpcrt4.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern int UuidCreateSequential(out Guid guid);
```

The question is - how can I know whether this method is safe to invoke from several threads simultaneously? Initial tests show that this might be safe, but I haven't found any significant information regarding this on MSDN or Google. Is there any standard convention regarding calls to the windows API that I can rely on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally safe to assume that most of the Windows API is thread-safe.

A globally unique ID should be able to be created from any application on the system at any time.  Therefore I would say thread-safety is a required feature of a GUID generator.  [RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122) describes a method for generating GUIDs which should be fairly close to what Windows actually does.  Note that it mentions obtaining a global lock which would be necessary to ensure simultaneous calls to create a GUID cannot get the same value.